# interpolation tan

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm trying to work out a tan interpolation passing through 3 points $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3)$, and which doesn't vanish on some interval including those three points.

If anyone would have any tip on how to get to some similar result, I'd be very thankful, thanks.

Comment: Given 3 points, I need to find a tan interpolation which doesn't vanish on an interval $[a,b]$

Comment: What is the definition of a "tan interpolation"?

Comment: Well, I'm just looking for an interpolation that can be written as a sum of tangent functions. Sorry if I wasn't specific enough :)